# Making a bug report command but kept getting "Type Error: client.fetchUser is not a function" Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Just like the title says, I want to make a bug report command that will send me the report.
But I kept getting this for some reason:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.fetchUser is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
var lockedList = []; //replace the userID stuff here with the ID's of the users you want to blacklist
const pfix = "h."
const arg = message.content.slice(pfix.length).split(/ +/);
const commnd = arg.shift().toLowerCase();
const person = message.author.username;
const userID = message.author.id;

if (commnd === 'bugreport') {

  if (userID == lockedList) {
    message.channel.send('***You have abused and f##ked this feature before so you\'re in our blacklist***')
    } else {
  let bug = arg.slice(0).join(' ');

  if (!bug) {
    message.channel.send('Huh?! What and Where\'s the f##king bug?!')
  } else {
  client.fetchUser(myID).then((user) => {
    user.send(`${person} of ${message.guild.name} (Guild ID: ${message.guild.id}, User ID: ${userID}) reported the bug: ${bug}`);
  });
  message.reply('**Your bug was reported. If you abuse and f##k this feature, you\'ll be blacklisted and stopped from using this command.**');
};
};
};
```

Side notes:

> This code is inside the `client.on('message', async message => {`
>
> I have some codes that is just copied from this one, the feedback and suggest command. Just saying this because it might be related to the problem.

Comment: What version of discord.js? What's `client`? I see a `User.fetch(id)`, and `client.users.fetch()` (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 the `fetchUser()` method was removed.

You should instead use [`client.users.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
client.users.fetch(myID).then((user) => {
  user.send(`${person} of ${message.guild.name} (Guild ID: ${message.guild.id}, User ID: ${userID}) reported the bug: ${bug}`);
})
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I just started discord.js like 2 weeks ago, this site is awesome